# Oracle query to avoid duplicates without primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

Excel datatable table1

```
ID    Name
-----------
xx    yy
zz    bb
yy    ll
```

Database Table2

```
ID   Name
----------
jj    kk
xx    yy
zz    bb
```

Desired output:

```
ID   Name
----------
jj    kk
yy    ll
```

I need a query from above where we have excel data which I need to load into Oracle SQL and I need a query where it should avoid duplicates loading in to database.

Comment: Hi - 1) please format your datasets as tables so that they are readable 2) “I need a query…” is not a question; please update your question with the SQL that you’ve managed to write and then ask a question about the specific issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UNION ALL` operator to merge your table's result sets, then use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses to get just non-duplicate records :

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  union all
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
) AS s
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```